# how do I do a deepEqual assertion on codewars?

Tags: qunit

I think they are using qunitjs, but I'm not sure.

```
Test.assertDeepEqual(solution('abc'), ['ab', 'c_'], 'abc failed')

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'assertDeepEqual'
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are using QUnit then the correct syntax would be:

```
QUnit.test("some test name", function(assert) {
  assert.deepEqual(solution('abc'), ['ab', 'c_'], 'abc failed');
});
```

So either they are not using QUnit, or they are and do not have the syntax correct.